# Changing GGPLOTLY graphs interaction in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I would like for the graphs in my shiny app to change color (or be highlighted) when I hover over them with my mouse. I would also like them to only output the count of my graph, instead of the count and the x-value.

Here is what it looks like in my Shiny App:
[image]

To be clear, I would like the bar that I am hovering over to turn light blue (or have a black outline) and to only say "count: 61735" without saying "fat_infreq(race): Black".

Below, I have attached a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(shinythemes)
library(forcats)
require(stringi)
require(stringr)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggthemes)
library(forcats)
library(xtable)
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)
library(gridExtra)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(vroom)
library(utf8)
library(tableHTML)
library(bslib)
library(devtools)
library(readr)
library(RColorBrewer)

ethnicity <- c("Hispanic", "Non-hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","White","White","White","White", 
               "White","Hispanic","Hispanic", "Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","White","White","White","White")
filtered_data <- data.frame(ethnicity)

ui <- fluidPage(

    
    titlePanel("Example"),
        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput("ethnicity_barplot")
        )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$ethnicity_barplot <- renderPlotly({
        ggplotly({
            ethnicity_barplot <-ggplot(data = filtered_data, aes(x = fct_infreq(ethnicity))) + 
                geom_bar() + 
                xlab("Ethnicity") + 
                ylab("Number of People") + 
                labs(title = "Ethnicity of Defendants in New York State Courts") + 
                geom_bar(fill = "#327EC2") + 
                theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))+
                theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))+
                theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
                geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust = -.3)
            
            ethnicity_barplot
        })
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

(Not all the packages are needed, just can't remember the ones that are)

Comment: Please edit to identify which libraries are actually necessary here (perhaps shiny, ggplot2, plotly is enough) so that other people can run your code without loading 29 (!!!!!) libraries almost all of which clearly unrelated to this. Furthermore, how many lines of your ggplot are necessary to demonstrate the question? (The titling and theme ones seem superfluous to me, and I'm not sure why you have two overlapping geom_bar() lines.)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ethnicity <- c(
  "Hispanic", "Non-hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "White", "White", "White", "White",
  "White", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "White", "White", "White", "White"
)
filtered_data <- data.frame(ethnicity)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example"),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("ethnicity_barplot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ethnicity_barplot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      p = {
        ethnicity_barplot <- ggplot(data = filtered_data, aes(x = fct_infreq(ethnicity))) +
          geom_bar() +
          xlab("Ethnicity") +
          ylab("Number of People") +
          labs(title = "Ethnicity of Defendants in New York State Courts") +
          geom_bar(fill = "#327EC2") +
          theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
          theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
          theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
          geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count..), vjust = -.3)

        ethnicity_barplot
      },
      # only show the y values (counts) as tooltips
      tooltip = "y"
    ) %>%
      # highlight current label
      layout(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "orange"), hoveron = list(bgcolor = "red"))
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```